# How to check a variable against 2 different strings? 9 line example

Tags: python, variables

Why doesn't this work?

```
rank=input("Is the realm a duchy, kingdom or empire? ")  
if rank=="duchy"or"Duchy":  
    realm=input("What is the duchy named? ")  
elif rank=="kingdom"or"Kingdom":  
    realm=input("What is the kingdom named? ")  
elif rank=="empire"or"Empire":  
    realm=input("What is the empire named? ")  
else:  
    print("Restart and say duchy, kingdom or empire. ")
```

No matter my answer, I get asked what the duchy is named.

Comment: Try `if rank=="duchy" or rank=="Duchy":`

Comment: Or ```if rank.lower() == 'duchy'```.

Answer (score 0):

It's evaluating `if "Dutchy"`, which returns `True`

you need

```
if rank=="duchy"or rank == "Duchy":
```

or better yet,

```
if rank.lower() == "duchy":
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about the boolean basics... Thanks a bunch :).

Answer (score 0):

The bug in your code is in this `if statement`:

```
if rank=="duchy"or"Duchy":  
# it equals
if rank == "duchy" or bool("Duchy"):
# equals
if rank == "duchy" or True:
# equals
if True:
```

So, no matter what your `rank` is, the `or "duchy"` will always make this be `True`. You have many solutions on fixing this:

```
# Fix your "or" statement
if rank =="duchy" or rank == "Duchy":

# Use "in" keyword
if rank in ("duchy", "Duchy"):

# Use "string.capitalize()"
if rank.capitalize() == "Duchy":
```